# iPhone 4 image resolution and image size

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am totally in confusion. Apple told that in iPhone 4 one can use high resolution image...
than the standard one.So i use 2 image(image@2x.png and image.png)...

image@2x.png has 50*50 dimension and 72 resolution
image.png    has 25*25 dimension and 72 resolution

than when i run the code

```
UIImage *image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"];
            CCTexture2D  *tex = [ [CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image ];
            [image release];

            CCSprite *u = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:tex  rect:CGRectMake(0, 0,25, 25)];
```

in iPhone 4 i think image@2x.png should load and it loaded but the image is cut...i don't get the full image......

but when i take this...

image@2x.png has 25*25 dimension and 144 resolution
image.png    has 25*25 dimension and 72 resolution

the image didn't cut and all ok......don't know why??

Another thing....when i use this..

```
UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BGS.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

it works as like apple said....then is it the prob with cocos2d?? i am using cocos2d.99.4..

Comment: Please add units, 25px, 25pt, 144px/in.
Btw. iPhone 4 resolution is: 326px/in but 163pt/in, iPhone 3G and iPhone 3GS resolution is 163px/in and 163pt/in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d textures use the CGImage property of the UIImage.  The scale factor of CGImages is assumed to be 1, but on a iPhone 4 UIImages have a scale factor of 2, so this is why you see the cropping that you do.

What version of cocos2d are you using? v0.99.4 has support for retina display, so just upgrading your library may fix your issue.